# What's the easiest way to work out the difference between two positive integers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math

I just need to know the difference between two int variables `a` and `b`.

I'm new to Objective-C.

Comment: `int` (NSInteger) or `unsigned int` (NSUInteger) or NSNumber?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int diff = a - b;
```

or if you need the *absolute difference*:

```
int abs_diff = abs(a - b);
```

and if there is any chance that your expression might overflow:

```
int abs_diff = max(a, b) - min(a, b);
```

Comment: +1, answer revoked. Someone who knows is better than someone who's guessing.

Comment: @GregS: Thanks - Garry didn't actually say *absolute difference* but I've now covered that possibility too.

Comment: @GregS: Sorry, I meant absolute difference :)